# restore zsys history in grub for ubuntu 20.04 (or revert to a previous state in command line)

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS on my Dell XPS-L702X.

Is it possible with `zsys` to revert the machine to a previous state (I mean a complete state, of course, like the ones you can find on the boot menu) without rebooting, not from GRUB menu, I mean from command line?

The problem is that I’ve used an application (grub customizer) and now my GRUB doesn’t show the history any more. Everything else, in GRUB and in the system, works with no problem, but it was not possible restore the history.

I tried:
a) to rollback bpool/BOOT/ubuntu to a snapshot
b) to reinstall zsys
c) to reinstall grub2
d) to remove grub customizer
e) `zsysctl boot prepare`
f) `zsysctl service reload`
g) `zsysctl service refresh`
h) `zsysctl boot update-menu`
i) to launch boot repair (doesn’t work, don’t know why… it says "LegacyWindows detected. Please enable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB)".but I set the compatibility and it says still so.

I've also tried from live-USB.

So I thought: if I could restore a full machine state, everything should be resolved…

thank you very much

Comment: Definitely not a good idea to install anything over the top of grub on a zfs root system (grub customizer). I know this is old but FYI anyone who comes across this.